# Путаница с сигнатурами хэндлеров асинхронных функций boost.Asio

Tags: c++, boost, асинхронность, asio, boost.asio

Не могу понять, почему я не могу вызывать функцию async_accept с параметрами, указанными в main в коде ниже. Я знаю что сигнатура хэндлера async_accept следующая: `void (*handler)(const boost::system::error_code&)`, но почему я могу передавать в async_accept функции с совершенно иной сигнатурой(используя bind), но не могу передать именно метод ReceiveMessage,хотя функцию out(с сигнатурой `void out(Session::SessionSharedPtr session)`) я передать могу. В случае же с `std::bind(&Session::ReceiveMessage, session, outFunc);`компилятор пишет `No matching member function for call to 'async_accept'` . Т.е в обоих случаях сигнатуры функций отличаются от заданной, но на случай с функцией out, компилятор не ругается, а с членом класса ReceiveMessage ругается. Как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>{
private:
    tcp::socket sock;
    std::string message;
    uint16_t maxMessageLength;
private:
    Session(boost::asio::io_context& context, uint16_t maxMessageLength);
    void onRead(std::function<void()> handler);
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Session> SessionSharedPtr;
public:
    static SessionSharedPtr CreateNewSession(boost::asio::io_context& context, short messageLength = 2048);
    void ReceiveMessage(std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)> handler);
    void SendMessage(std::string& message, std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)> handler);
    std::string& GetMessage();
    tcp::socket& GetSocket();
    ~Session();
};

Session::Session(boost::asio::io_context &context, uint16_t maxMessageLength) : sock(context)
{
    this->maxMessageLength = maxMessageLength;
    message.resize(maxMessageLength);
}

Session::SessionSharedPtr Session::CreateNewSession(boost::asio::io_context &context, short messageLength) {
    return Session::SessionSharedPtr(new Session(context, messageLength));
}

void Session::ReceiveMessage(std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)> handler) {
    sock.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(message, maxMessageLength), handler);
}

void Session::SendMessage(std::string &messageToSend,
                          std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code &, size_t)> handler) {
    sock.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(messageToSend, maxMessageLength), handler);
}

Session::~Session() {
    sock.close();
}

std::string &Session::GetMessage() {
    return message;
}

tcp::socket &Session::GetSocket() {
    return sock;
}

void Session::onRead(std::function<void()> handler) {
    handler();
}

void out(Session::SessionSharedPtr session){
    std::cout << session->GetMessage();
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(context);
    auto session = Session::CreateNewSession(context);
    auto outFunc = std::bind(out, session);
    auto readFunc = std::bind(&Session::ReceiveMessage, session, outFunc);
    acceptor.async_accept(session->GetSocket(), readFunc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы наверно шутите? Что это за дурацкий вопрос: сигнатуры отличаются - как это исправить? Сделать сигнатуры верными!!!

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я не могу понять как это работает, почему в одном случае я могу использовать отличающуюся сигнатуру, а в другом нет

Comment: приведите компилируемый пример того, как вы используете функцию с отличающейся сигнатурой

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в коде выше, если в async_accept вместо readFunc передать outFunc, код скомпилируется, но у функции out отличающаяся сигнатура.

Comment: хм, видимо документация не совсем полная - такая сигнатура функции приемлима, просто не описана. Не нужно думать, что не описанная == не приемлимая